# Microsoft B2C Azure Demo Not Authorized Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, authentication, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to learn ASP.Net with Azure AD B2C Login / Register flow. I am running the demo here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-web-api-dotnet?tabs=app-reg-ga

The C# code for the demo can be downloaded from https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi/archive/master.zip

I have gone all the way through the demo from the beginning and have completed all of the pre-requisites.

I am at the point now where I have signed in successfully and when I click the To-Do List link while debugging the application, I get a User Not Authorized (404) error.

I apologize in advance if I am not explaining what I think I am seeing very well, as I am very new to Azure and web programming. I am most comfortable with Windows Desktop applications interfacing with SQL Server, but I am trying to expand my knowledge, so please bear with me.

As I stated before, I can successfully log-in to the application, which I believe happens in the TaskWebApp project.

Here is the code where the error is happening, which is in the TasksController.cs in the TaskWebApp project:

```
namespace TaskWebApp.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class TasksController : Controller
    {
        private readonly string apiEndpoint = Globals.ServiceUrl + "/api/tasks/";

        // GET: Makes a call to the API and retrieves the list of tasks
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            try
            {
                // Retrieve the token with the specified scopes
                var scope = new string[] { Globals.ReadTasksScope };
                
                IConfidentialClientApplication cca = MsalAppBuilder.BuildConfidentialClientApplication();
                var accounts = await cca.GetAccountsAsync();
                AuthenticationResult result = await cca.AcquireTokenSilent(scope, accounts.FirstOrDefault()).ExecuteAsync();
                
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, apiEndpoint);

                // Add token to the Authorization header and make the request
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

                // Handle the response
                switch (response.StatusCode)
                {
                    case HttpStatusCode.OK:
                        string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        JArray tasks = JArray.Parse(responseString);
                        ViewBag.Tasks = tasks;
                        return View();
                    case HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized:
                        return ErrorAction("Please sign in again. " + response.ReasonPhrase);
                    default:
                        return ErrorAction("Error. Status code = " + response.StatusCode + ": " + response.ReasonPhrase);
                }
            }
            catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
            {
                /*
                    If the tokens have expired or become invalid for any reason, ask the user to sign in again.
                    Another cause of this exception is when you restart the app using InMemory cache.
                    It will get wiped out while the user will be authenticated still because of their cookies, requiring the TokenCache to be initialized again
                    through the sign in flow.
                */
                return new RedirectResult("/Account/SignUpSignIn?redirectUrl=/Tasks");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ErrorAction("Error reading to do list: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

The response status code in the Switch statement is 404.

When I debug, here is what I see:

var scope returns https://ShoppingCartB2C.onmicrosoft.com/tasks/demo.read

cca returns (I am questioning the format of the Authority property):

[image]

accounts returns nothing. A count of 0.

[image]

I believe 0 accounts is the problem.

When I try to get result, it goes to the catch block.

Here is the Web.config for the TaskWebApp project:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="ida:Tenant" value="ShoppingCartB2C.onmicrosoft.com" />
    <!--MSAL cache needs a tenantId along with the user's objectId to function. It retrieves these two from the claims returned in the id_token. 
        As tenantId is not guaranteed to be present in id_tokens issued by B2C unless the steps listed in this 
        document (https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AAD-B2C-specifics#caching-with-b2c-in-msalnet). 
        If you are following the workarounds listed in the doc and tenantId claim (tid) is available in the user's token, then please change the 
        code in <ClaimsPrincipalsExtension.cs GetB2CMsalAccountId()> to let MSAL pick this from the claims instead -->
    <add key="ida:TenantId" value="db1b052a-415c-4604-887c-e27b59860001" />
    <add key="ida:ClientId" value="975f1457-e3e2-4cb8-b069-6b0b6b46611d" />
    <add key="ida:ClientSecret" value="Gw4.3o-DRDr.j_828H-JMfsk_Jd1d-jQ5p" />
    <add key="ida:AadInstance" value="https://ShoppingCartB2C.b2clogin.com/tfp/{0}/{1}" />
    <add key="ida:RedirectUri" value="https://localhost:44316/" />
    <add key="ida:SignUpSignInPolicyId" value="B2C_1_signupsignin1" />
    <add key="ida:EditProfilePolicyId" value="b2c_1_profileediting1" />
    <add key="ida:ResetPasswordPolicyId" value="b2c_1_passwordreset1" />
    <add key="api:TaskServiceUrl" value="https://localhost:44332/" />
    <!-- The following settings is used for requesting access tokens -->
    <add key="api:ApiIdentifier" value="https://ShoppingCartB2C.onmicrosoft.com/tasks/" />
    <add key="api:ReadScope" value="demo.read" />
    <add key="api:WriteScope" value="demo.write" />
  </appSettings>
```

And for the TaskService project:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="ida:AadInstance" value="https://ShoppingCartB2C.b2clogin.com/{0}/{1}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
    <add key="ida:Tenant" value="ShoppingCartB2C.onmicrosoft.com" />
    <add key="ida:ClientId" value="975f1457-e3e2-4cb8-b069-6b0b6b46611d" />
    <add key="ida:SignUpSignInPolicyId" value="B2C_1_signupsignin1" />
    <!-- The following settings is used for requesting access tokens -->
    <add key="api:ReadScope" value="demo.read" />
    <add key="api:WriteScope" value="demo.write" />
  </appSettings>
```

If you would like screen shots from Azure, or have questions about how that is configured, feel free to ask.

I am not concerned about exposing client secrets or AppId's because I am just following a demo. This is never going to be a production app.

I have not made any code modifications to the demo. Thanks for your help.

Edit: Showing API Permissions
[image]

Comment: You should have two app registrations, one for your client and one for your api.

Comment: Thank you @jas. I must have gotten confused when I went through the demo. I exposed the API and configured the permissions for the client. I'll fix it after I get home from work today and let you know how it goes.